# AttributeError:'module' object has no attribute indexing

Tags: python, function, import, lucene, attributeerror

I am trying to use all functions of a certain python `news_Lucene.py` script in another python script `ProcesosContinuos.py`. I have the following structure for `news_Lucene.py` which I am importing in my `ProcesosContinuous.py`.

Code for `news_Lucene()`:

```
class news_Lucene():

    @staticmethod
    def indexing():
         #some code

    @staticmethod
    def get_set_terms(reader):
         #some code

    @staticmethod
    def get_TFIDF():
         #some code

    @staticmethod
    def get_author_TFIDF():
         #some code
#SOME CODE OUTSIDE STATIC METHODS
```

In `ProcesosContinuous.py` I am trying the following:

```
from engines.extras.download_datos_desambiguar import news_Lucene

news_Lucene().indexing()
```

I have also tried

`indexing()`

but it still doesn't work. It says `AttributeError:'module' object has no attribute indexing`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You imported the *module*, not the class object contained *in* the module.

Use:

```
news_Lucene.news_Lucene().indexing()
```

or import the class:

```
from engines.extras.download_datos_desambiguar.news_Lucene import news_Lucene
```

The [Python styleguide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends you use only lowercase_characters_with_underscores for your module names, and CamelCase for class names; this helps avoid confusing your modules and classes.

To comply with the style guide, rename your module and your class; the module name could be `news_lucene`, the class name `NewsLucene`.

I note that your whole class consists of nothing but static methods. If that is the sole purpose of the class, you need to *remove* the class altogether. Just make everything a top-level function instead. Python is not Java, you do not need to use classes at all if that doesn't make sense for your problem at hand.

Comment: Thanks! But can you tell me what I should do to call all the functions of the class `news_Lucene()` at once? Instead of calling it one by one?

Comment: @kaushaya: create one function that calls the others?

Comment: In my code of `news_Lucene()`, `f3()` calls `f2()`. So if I just call `f3()` will it be able to access `f2()`?

Comment: @kaushaya: functions in a module can access all the other functions in the same module.

Comment: There is some code outside the static method. How do I access that?

Comment: In short, I need to call the execute the entire class in form of a function. Is that possible?

Comment: @kaushaya: *just make it a function*. You are not storing state here.

Comment: @kaushaya: calling other functions in your module is *pretty basic Python* though.

Comment: @kaushaya: you are also now expanding and expanding on your original question. If you have a new question, perhaps it is time to create a new post?

Comment: I just said that there is some other code outside the static functions. Sorry for not mentioning that in the original post. But you see, it's working. When I call the function. But it gives me some globalization error regarding some variables. So I was wondering if there is a way to call the entire class like a function.

Comment: @kaushaya: classes are not functions, you cannot treat them as such.